# PHPUnit from command line - list of dependancy files displayed. How can I make it display only the test script?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have installed PHPUnit on Windows 7, with PHP and Pear.

I have a basic test script, to start with:

```
<?php

class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

I'm running it from the command prompt as:

```
phpunit unittest testTest.php
```

And getting the following return:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) StackTest::testTest
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint.php:145
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint.php:92
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\Assert.php:2100
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\Assert.php:854
C:\Users\lbassett\Dropbox\Projects\Test\testTest.php:10
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:939
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:801
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php:649
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:748
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:772
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:745
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:325
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:187
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:125
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\phpunit:44

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

My problem is the long list of different files listed.

I only want to see my test scrip there. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am also getting this problem, when running phpunit.phar on Windows. Output is e.g. phar://C:/xampp/php/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Version:

It's a bug in PHPUnit. [I've fixed it.](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/3fd14394092288f2cc9891131fd1c2cb964ef4e5) With the next minor release it will work.

---

#### Long Version:

You have already noticed that your file is included in the backtrace

```
 C:\Users\lbassett\Dropbox\Projects\Test\testTest.php:10
```

so the question is why is there all that other stuff around your classes.

PHPUnit **should** filter that backtrace and strip out all the PHPUnit classes but for some reasons that seems to not work.

The output on linux:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) failingTest::testFail
Failed asserting that false is true.

/home/edo/phpunit-dev/oneFailingTest/failingTest.php:6
```

I at first was expecting an issue with the spaces in `Program Files` but I've installed it in a folder without spaces and it "breaks" there too.

For me this is a bug in PHPUnit.

<strike>I suggest [**`you file an issue at the github issue tracker`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) that the backtrace filtering seems broken on windows and I'll see if I can take care of that then.</strike> **Edit: [I've pushed a fix](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/3fd14394092288f2cc9891131fd1c2cb964ef4e5). It should be solved in `PHPUnit 3.6.6` (when it is released). See the edits.**

---

Edit: Yeah. The issue seems to come from PHPUnit_Util_Filter::phpunitFiles(); returning the paths with `\` instead of `/`.

#### Fix

If you put the following code in: `PHPUnit/Util/GlobalState.php` at line 412. (Before the return statement)

```
foreach(self::$phpunitFiles as $key => $value) {
    unset(self::$phpunitFiles[$key]);
    self::$phpunitFiles[str_replace("/", "\\", $key)] = $value;
}
```

then you get a nice looking backtrace. I'll see to it that it gets fixed in 3.6.6 with a nicer patch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your patch and it didn't work I'm afraid. Is there something obvious I may have missed (I'm very new to PHPUnit)?

Comment: Maybe just copy/paste the whole PHPUnit/Util/GlobalState.php file https://raw.github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/3fd14394092288f2cc9891131fd1c2cb964ef4e5/PHPUnit/Util/GlobalState.php over and see if that helps. If not maybe make sure you are editing the right PHPUnit (in case pear has installed two or something? It should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\` if that doesn't help ether you could debug that in `PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php` , var_dump $frame and isset($blacklist[$frame['file']]) and open up a bug with the output :)