# Is it possible to mimic PHPUnit's output-to-console results using a Listener?

Tags: php, phpunit

## Situation

I'm implementing a Listener for PHPUnit that will record test results to a DB for later review.  I like the default information `phpunit` outputs to console when a failure, error, skipped, or incomplete test is encountered.

Example:

```
1) sandbox_ExtensionSampleTest::testError
printf(): Too few arguments

E:\ecom_testing\tests_v2\TestSuites\sandbox\Base.php:28
E:\ecom_testing\tests_v2\TestSuites\sandbox\ExtensionSampleTest.php:37
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:939
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:801
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php:649
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:748
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:772
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:745
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:325
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:187
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:125
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php\pear\phpunit:44

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Note: I did find listing all the PHPUnit dependencies in the output is [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576472/phpunit-from-command-line-list-of-dependancy-files-displayed-how-can-i-make-i), but the example above still shows two related test files.

## Question

One of the parameters for an implemented listener method is `Exception $e`.  I can get the message as well as the first line using `$e`, but I can't seem to get the rest of the lines.

After reading Exceptions in the PHP manual, I thought using `$e->getPrevious()` would work... attempted to do the following:

```
// Storing in a array to put into a DB later
// First line with the message
$trace[] = sprintf(
    "%s\n\n%s:%s\n", 
    $e->getMessage(), 
    $e->getFile(), 
    $e->getLine()
);

// Go through the rest of the exceptions of files and lines
while ($e = $e->getPrevious()){
    $trace[] = sprintf(
        "%s:%s\n", 
        $e->getFile(), 
        $e->getLine()
    );
}
```

That didn't work.  It seems like `$e->getPrevious()` is empty and I did confirmed it when I dumped the object.  I thought something like `$e->getTraceAsString()` would yield the same results, but it's not what I expected (I haven't used exceptions much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of file and line number combinations is called the [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace). You can grab it as an array using [`Exception::getTrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php) and walk it yourself, or you can let PHPUnit filter out its classes for you by calling [`PHPUnit_Util_Filter::getFilteredStacktrace()`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php#L67). Pass the exception `$e` and `true` to receive a formatted string, or pass `false` to get the filtered array back instead.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!